# capistrano fails to deploy Sprockets::FileNotFound submodule file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano, git-submodules

I've got a Rails 3.2 app with capistrano 2 installed and I have a number of submodules. I just moved vendor/assets/javascripts/ui-utils to a submodule.

```
[submodule "app/assets/javascripts/jquery.autotab"]
    path = app/assets/javascripts/jquery.autotab
    url = git@github.com:map7/jquery.autotab.git
[submodule "app/assets/javascripts/jquery.overdrive"]
    path = app/assets/javascripts/jquery.overdrive
    url = git@github.com:map7/jquery.overdrive.git
[submodule "app/assets/javascripts/jquery.validationEngine"]
    path = app/assets/javascripts/jquery.validationEngine
    url = https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine.git
[submodule "app/assets/javascripts/keymaster"]
    path = app/assets/javascripts/keymaster
    url = git@github.com:map7/keymaster.git
[submodule "vendor/assets/javascripts/ui-utils"]
    path = vendor/assets/javascripts/ui-utils
    url = github.com:/map7/ui-utils.git
```

It's only the bottom submodule which I'm having trouble with. Could this be because it's in the vendor/assets area?

Now when I do a `cap deploy` I get the following error

```
  * executing "cd -- /srv/pais/releases/20140630042430 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets env RBENV_ROOT=\"/usr/local/rbenv\" PATH=\"/usr/local/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/rbenv/bin:$PATH\" RBENV_VERSION=\"2.1.1\" /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'ui-utils/modules/keypress/keypress.js'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] (in /srv/pais/releases/20140630042430/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:42)
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:102:in `resolve'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:142:in `require_asset'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:215:in `process_require_directive'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `block in process_directives'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:163:in `each'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:163:in `process_directives'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:97:in `evaluate'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:193:in `block in evaluate'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `each'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `evaluate'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `new'
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] /srv/pais/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `block in build_asset'
```

On my development machine this file does exist and works.

I've tried putting the following into my deploy.rb with no luck

```
set :git_enable_submodules, 1   # Get submodules
set :git_submodules_recursive, true
namespace :git do
  desc "Init & update submodules"
  task :update_submodules, :roles => :app do
    run("cd #{release_path} && git submodule init && git submodule update")
  end
end
before "deploy:assets:precompile", "git:update_submodules"
```

**Update 30/06/14**

Noticed that if I go to any of the other submodules and type `git status` then I get the following;

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

If I go to my ui-utils submodule and type `git status` I get

```
# HEAD detached at 4e86ac7
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I'm running git version 1.9.1, if I run the following

```
git submodule deinit -f vendor/assets/javascripts/ui-utils
```

Then try adding it again using

```
git submodule add git@github.com:map7/ui-utils.git vendor/assets/javascripts/ui-utils
```

I get the following error

```
A git directory for 'vendor/assets/javascripts/ui-utils' is found locally with remote(s):
  origin    https://github.com/map7/ui-utils.git
If you want to reuse this local git directory instead of cloning again from
  git@github.com:map7/ui-utils.git
use the '--force' option. If the local git directory is not the correct repo
or you are unsure what this means choose another name with the '--name' option.
```

**Update**

I managed to remove the vendor/assets/javascripts/ui-utils from git completely by following
[How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule?rq=1)

I've now added it again through submodule and now it's like the other submodules but I still get the deploy problem.

**Update**

If I use `cap --debug deploy` and stop it just before the error, then I ssh over to my server and do a git status I can see some problems with the submodule and capistrano on the server;

```
git status
# On branch deploy
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   deleted:    log/searchd.test.pid
#   modified:   vendor/assets/javascripts/ui-utils (modified content)
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   REVISION
#   app/assets/javascripts/jquery.autotab/
#   log
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and might keep this here. It was multiple things

1. I had to completely remove my submodule and add it again correctly
2. Had to remove `set :deploy_via, :remote_cache` from my deploy.rb file

`cap --debug deploy` helped a lot here.